# How to get lt, lg values from string

Tags: c#

I have below string, i need to extract lt, lg values into new dictionary if s : N

how to do this. please help me

"\n{\n\t1619059179095 : \n{\n\tac : 13.0990000;\n\tlg : 58.4269473;\n\tlt : 22.4404507;\n\ts : N\n}\n}"

Thanks
Krish

Comment: It looks like this is escaped and (unfortunately) malformed JSON. Where did you get this data from?

Comment: i am getting this data string from another GPS source(javascript). i need to format and extract these values from c#

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: Malformed is an understatement. `;` instead of `,`. Unquoted properties. Unquoted Value.

Comment: While a `stringJson.Replace(';', ',');` may unsafly clean the `;`. The major issue is the `s:N`... unquoted value will need a custom serializer on NaN. But it will work without it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/pULvwN